# Is this code snippet good enough for password hash and salt

Tags: passwords, hash, php, salt

After a few days reading up about salting and hashing passwords, I found an actual bit of code that tells how to do it. This is what I found:

```
$blowfish_salt = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(22));  
$hash = crypt($data, "$2a$12$".$blowfish_salt);
```

Is this a good way to do it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. It's easier to use the php 5.5 [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function, or if you're using an older version, the [compatibility library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php)
2. `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` sometimes suffers from performance issues. Consider `mcrypt_create_iv (size, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)` instead.
3. salt encoding is tricky. Hex doesn't use the space optimally, and normal Base64 uses invalid characters.

   ```
   $salt = substr(strtr(base64_encode($randomSalt), '+', '.'), 0, 22);
   ```

   should do the trick.

Combining these you get

```
$binarySalt = mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
$salt = substr(strtr(base64_encode($binarySalt), '+', '.'), 0, 22);
```

Check [Seven Ways To Screw Up BCrypt on ircmaxell's blog](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/12/seven-ways-to-screw-up-bcrypt.html) for further reading.

Comment: Thanks @CodesInChaos! (Remembering I am totally new to this)  would you mind putting the two suggestions together so that I can begin to understand how it should go? (I'd understand if you say no - but I have been going round and round for the last couple of days,for just that one code snippet and my brains are getting totally fried!)

Comment: @vinaya I recommend using the `password_hash` library I linked, instead of writing it yourself.

Comment: Some source related to the performance issues of `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`?

Comment: @gipi I don't remember the details, but I guess it was this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940168/openssl-random-pseudo-bytes-is-slow-php

Answer (score 2):

There isn't anything wrong with your code. However, I always prefer to use ready made libraries for password hashing whenever possible. For PHP, there is an excellent implementation available over at [PHPass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/).

```
require('PasswordHash.php');

$pwdHasher = new PasswordHash(8, FALSE);

$hash = $pwdHasher->HashPassword( $password );
```

Verification is done for you as well.

```
$checked = $pwdHasher->CheckPassword($password, $hash);
if ($checked) {
    echo 'password correct';
} else {
    echo 'wrong credentials';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it correctly. The salt you are generating is considered random and long enough (note a salt needs to be unique per password). You are also using bcrypt which is considered a secure password hashing algorithm.